# Out folder not generated when build and export are run by Github actions

Tags: next.js, github-actions, cicd

I use the standard script "build" which is set up as "npm run build && npm run export" - it works without issues locally, but somehow when I run it via Github actions, no "out" folder is generated, even though I'm not getting any issues.

Has anybody experienced this?

My Next version is ^13.4.5

Code for the Github action:

```
name: Build Static Website

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - name: Install dependencies
        run:  npm ci

      - name: Build Next.js app
        run: |
          npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the **dist** folder might be in the **.gitignore** file. Even though it shouldn't affect the action's ability to see the folder, it's worth checking to make sure you're not accidentally excluding it from some operation.

**Debugging:** Add a step just after the **Build Next.js app Action** to list the contents of the directory. This will allow you to see if the **dist** folder is indeed present after the build step.

There is also an issue on github that may be relevant to this.
https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/430#issuecomment-764445919

Hope this helps